# Extracting text from PDF - Rstudio

Tags: r, pdf, text, pdftotext

Using pdftools library, I was able to extract only 3 pages of pdf file which has 30 pages.
What can be the the issue?  How do I extract text from all the pages? First 3 pages contains normal text and many other pages contains tabular column

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting pdf into image format and then do the OCR part. [More info](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html)

Use `pdf_convert` function from the `pdftools` package

```
pngText <- pdftools::pdf_convert('https://jeroen.github.io/images/ocrscan.pdf', dpi = 600)
```

then,

```
text <- tesseract::ocr(pngText)
cat(text)
```

Let me know whether this works.